# jQuery rel attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, hover, toggle

We have many links with `rel` attributes:

```
<div class="team-tags">
 <a class="s1" rel="t1 t2 t3" href="#">One</a>
 <a class="s2" rel="t2 t3" href="#">Two</a>
 <a class="s3" rel="t1" href="#">Three</a>
 <a class="s4" rel="t4 t6" ref="#">Four</a>
 <a class="s5" rel="t2 t5" href="#">Five</a>
</div>
```

And one `ul`:

```
<ul class="team">
 <li class="t1">Some text</li>
 <li class="t2">Some text</li>
 <li class="t3">Some text</li>
 <li class="t4">Some text</li>
 <li class="t5">Some text</li>
 <li class="t6">Some text</li>
</ul>
```

`rel` of each link can have multiple values (like `class="value1 value2 value3 value4"`). Each value is used to mark similar `class` of `<li>`.

`rel="t2 t3"` marks `<li class="t2">Some text</li>` and `<li class="t3">Some text</li>`. And so on.

**The main idea** - when we `hover` any of these links, script should find `li`s with similar class inside `.team` list and toggle `active` class for them.

For example, if we `hover` link with `rel="t4 t6"`, script should toggle class `active` for `<li class="t4">Some text</li>` and `<li class="t6">Some text</li>`, like `<li class="t4 active">Some text</li>` and `<li class="t6 active">Some text</li>`.

jQuery 1.3.2 is used.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
function getTeams(elem) {
    return $('.' + elem.rel.replace(' ', ', .'));
}
$('.team-tags a[rel]').hover(
    function() { getTeams(this).addClass('active'); },
    function() { getTeams(this).removeClass('active'); }
);
```

## [Demo](http://jsbin.com/isodu3/edit)

Comment: Thanks, describe please how to implement this.

Comment: @Happy Just make sure its inside `$(function(){ ... })`, but that is all the code you need to make this work.

Comment: @Happy: That's your fault.  You're mis-calling `hover()`.

Comment: I found the bug, its all in last "});" the } is not needed. I have removed it and now it works. So, its your fault, edit your answer :)