# jQuery replace doesn't work

Tags: jquery, replace

Script replaces `rel` attributes to `class`.

**Full code** - http://jsbin.com/efozi3/8/

It doesn't work for links, where used more than 2 values in `rel`.

An example - the first item:

```
<a class="s1" rel="t1 t2 t3" href="#">One</a>
```

**First three** `<li>` **should become blue, but now only the first one does.**

```
 <li class="t1">
     <strong>1</strong>
 </li>
 <li class="t2">
      <strong>2</strong>
 </li>
 <li class="t3">
      <strong>3</strong>
 </li>
```

This line doesn't work as expected (supports maximum 2 values in `rel`):

```
return $('.' + elem.rel.replace(' ', ', .'));
```

You can edit code directly on http://jsbin.com/efozi3/8/edit/

Thanks.

Comment: (Why do people keep abusing `rel` for this kind of thing? What did that poor attribute do to deserve it?)

Comment: @bobince: To validate, perhaps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, Javascript's `replace` function only replaces the first occurrence of the search text.
To replace every occurrence, you need to pass a regex with the `g` (**G**lobal) flag.

Change it to

```
return $('.' + elem.rel.replace(/\s+/g, ', .'));
```

Comment: Sorry; I forgot about this quirk in [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238129/jquery-rel-attribute/3238187#3238187).

Comment: I guess there's no other way (except looping until string remains unchanged). Doesn't seem like cheating to me...

Comment: @Koen: That's not what he meant (I believe).  [I gave him his current code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238129/jquery-rel-attribute/3238187#3238187)